# How to create a list in batch coding

Tags: list, batch-file

I want to expand my games by adding an inventory. I'd assume that the best way of doing this would be to use a list. The only problem is that I don't how to use a list or if it even exists in batch.

Comment: There is only one variable type in batch: `string`. If you are ready backslapping you might read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45492486/6811411)

Comment: So a variable and a list would be the same thing?

Comment: It's still just a string. The method only creates a (pseudo) array from a string list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/22194718    http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3244

Comment: I suggest you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) in previous linked topic...